# How can I find the changes in a single column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a "csv" file which includes 3 columns, 100+rows. The variables in all columns change according to the data placed in Column 1, the "Time".

```
Time    Temp    Cloud
1100    22  1
1102    14  1
1104    14  2
1106    23  1
1108    12  1
1110    21  2
1112    17  2
1114    12  3
1116    24  3
```

I want to know when "Cloud" changes [ e.g. at 3rd and 6th row ], and I want to obtain the other variables which is placed at that row, and the row before that row.
How can I do that ?
Thanks

Comment: You could use `rle` for this.

Comment: I tried that Tim, but as a beginner, I just couldn't do it.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you wrote what you had tried, what worked, and what didn't work.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you want your output to look like for the provided example data. For example, it looks to me like "cloud" changes at the third, fourth, sixth, and eighth rows.

Comment: I want to learn which "Temp" causes the change in "Cloud" and its "Time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` will almost do this directly.  Apply it twice.  Calling your example data `d`:

```
> d[c(diff(d$Cloud) != 0,FALSE) | c(FALSE, diff(d$Cloud) != 0),]
  Time Temp Cloud
2 1102   14     1
3 1104   14     2
4 1106   23     1
5 1108   12     1
6 1110   21     2
7 1112   17     2
8 1114   12     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
df$Change <- c(0,sign(diff(df$Cloud)))
subset(df,Change!=0)[,4]
```

This will eliminate rows where there are no changes.